# Powershell Script for spotting incorrect preprocessor directives

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, scripting, powershell-ise

I need to check for every '#define' in my project files if its value is inside parentheses.
For example:

```
#define A (50)
#define B (60)
#define C 70
```

I want to spot all the files that contain a wrong format of the #define in order to manually correct it.

I'd like to automate this task by running a little powershell script but i'm stuck at implementing it. This is what i wrote so far:

```
GetChildItem -Recurse | Select-String "#define" /*some additional code*/ -List | Select Path
```

Any solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are looking for parentheses, you may try `Select-String -Pattern '#define.*?\(.*?\)'`. If you don't want parentheses, you may try `Select-String -Pattern '#define[^()]+$'`. It would be best to make the match more granular, but I don't know all of your pattern possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
... |Select-String '^#define(?!\s+[\w]+\s+\([^\)]+\)\s*$)'
```

... should do.

The regex pattern breaks down as:

```
^                   # start of line
 #define            # followed by literal string "#define"
 (?!                # negative look-ahead for
    \s+             # 1 or more whitespace chars
    [\w]+           # 1 or more words characters
    \s+             # 1 or more whitespace chars
    \([^\)]+\)      # literal "(" followed by 1 or more non-"(", and finally a literal ")"
    \s*             # trailing whitespace
    $               # end of string
 )                  # end negative look-ahead
```

In other words, we're looking for lines that:

- has a `#define` directive,
- which is *not* well-formed

Comment: Yes, is called regexes  https://powershellexplained.com/2017-07-31-Powershell-regex-regular-expression/